# Запросить положительное число не больше 1000 (переспрашивать, в случае ошибки ввода) и вывести на экран через запятую все положительные чётные числа

Tags: c++, c

Запросить положительное число не больше 1000 (переспрашивать, в случае ошибки ввода) и вывести на экран через запятую все положительные чётные числа.

Пробовал использовать цикл `while`, условие `if(k < 0 && k > 1000)` типа того

Comment: Точно все-все положительные четные?...

Comment: ваше условие никогда не выполнится. число не может быть меньше нуля и одновременно больше тысячи.

Comment: AlexGlebe, подскажите как будет правильно?)))

Comment: нужен весь код с вашей попыткой и полный правильный текст задачи

Comment: вероятно, подразумевалось: `||`, а не `&&`

Comment: С или С++, выбирайте один.

Comment: Точнее **Си** будет

Comment: `вывести на экран через запятую все положительные чётные числа` - наверное меньше запрошенного числа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программа гораздо проще и короче. Не надо много функций и проверок на делимость.

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int limit = 1001;
    while(limit < 0 || limit > 1000) // запрашиваем пока пользователь не введет правильное число
    {
        printf("\nВведите целое положительное число меньше 1000 = ");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i += 2) // выводим четные числа
        printf("%d, ", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно, только еще включить нужно то число  введенное пользователем. Спасибо☺

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так

```
using namespace std;
void zapros();
void ccc(int);
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");  
zapros(); //вызываем функцию ввода

}
void zapros()
{
int chislo;
cout << "Введите число: ";
cin >> chislo;
ccc(chislo); //вызываем функцию счета

}
void ccc(int chislo1)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
if (chislo1 > 1000)
{
    cout << "\nЧисло больше 1000";
    zapros();
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < chislo1; i++) //проходим по всем числам
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) //проверяем на нечетность
        {
            cout << i << " ,";
        }
    }  
 }
 }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хорошо, закомментировал код

Comment: Я не знаю, что это, но это точно не C/C++. C#?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, c#. Мне показалось, что в теме c#)) Но все-равно цикл на плюсах также выглядеть может

Comment: Да, верно))) Я заметил уже, отсюда полезное взять можно разве что :  "for (int i = 0; i < vvod; i++)" и        "if (i % 2 == 0) ", "if (vvod > 1000)"

Comment: Вроде немного помогло из выше данного ответа, осталось малость подправить

Comment: Зачем проверять на делимость, если можно просто `i` увеличивать на 2 и распечатывать? `for(int i=0; i<vvod; i+=2) printf("%d, ", i);` И зачем делать перекрестные вызовы функций `zapros ()` и `ccc()`. А для такой маленькой программы вообще нет смысла разбивать по функциям.

Comment: @AlekSandr ответ переделал на плюсы

Comment: @Teslaaaaa1 Зачем вы делаете перекрестные вызовы? Здесь вполне линейный код.

Comment: @DmitryK это просто первая мысль, которая мне в голову пришла